# Magento connect manager showing login screen in console

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

Magento connect manager showing login screen in console.

I have installed 1.9.1.0 ver of magento, Want to upgrade my extension.
But when i select any extension version for upgrade and click on commit changes button. It scroll me to console area and shows login page of connect manager instead of console window.
After putting credential of connect manager it gives message that "No actions selected".
But all these functionality is working fine on Local side.
[Please see the image of console is showing login form of connect manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5LYn.png)

Please help me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

This screen signifies that magento requires your authentication check .

so please provide admin username  and password of magento store

Comment: Ya i have provided admin username and password but after that it gives message that "No actions selected".

Comment: It appeared that I had set my Firefox browser to Do Not Track and Never remember history. After changing those settings I was able to use the Magento Connect Manager without the no action selected error.